# Flash render bug in Chrome

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, render

Look at this bug,

this is the code: "We have a simple webpage with an iframe that is very big and is moved to the left, we are seeing the center part of it. Then with javascript we add a flash object (a clock) in the middle (position 1000x1000) so it is in the visible section of the iframe. At first the flash piece is well rendered but after the "magic" steps that i mention here the flash piece is not rendered"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<iframe id="iframe" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; width:2000px; height: 2000px; border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
window[0].document.write('<body><div id="FlashContainer" style="display: inline;"><embed id="embed" name="embed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" src="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" swliveconnect="true" style="vertical-align: top; margin: 0px; width: 728px; height: 300px; clip: rect(0px 728px 300px 0px); position: absolute; left: 1000px; top: 1000px; z-index: 1;"></div></body>');
window[0].document.body.style.paddingLeft = "1000px"; //without this works
window[0].document.body.style.paddingTop = "1000px"; //without this works
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Run this code in Chrome, open the devtool (F12):

Select the element embed:

1. Change the values:

   - postion: relative
   - left: 0px
   - top: 0px

     - (Some times the flash is not rendered here!)
2. Change again to:

   - position: absolute
   - left: 1200
   - top: 1200

Comment: with these two steps, we moved the embed element to the left top corner of the iframe, and then we restored the original position

So, where is the bug? The bug is that the flash element is not rendered (Can be in step 1 or 2). To check it, press right click (on the left top corner of the viewport) and the flash popup menu should appear.

That is not all folks! if you change the display property of the element "FlashContainer", then the flash piece appears there!

Note: the problem is caused by the padding left & top, I couldn't figure out why is this happening.

Thank you!

Comment: Try just using window instead of window[0].

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the z-index for the iframe to 1 or greater.